# What are the correct parameters for collecting card data when using STPAddCardViewController as a view controller?

Tags: json, swift, stripe-payments

I have an app where I have a view controller designed in storyboard that is a class of STPAddCardViewController.  The view controller displays correctly, and when I enter in all of my credit card info, or scan it in, that process works with no problem, as far as I can tell.

When I hit "done" it is not adding the card.  I know the wiring up of the "done" button works, because I have programmed it to display an UIAlertController alert as a test.  It also parsing through my code because I am receiving a JSON response back from Stripe.

I have put in breakpoints to step through the code and I see that cardParams is always null.  This is where I think the problem may lie.

AddPaymentVC:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Stripe
import Firebase
import Alamofire
import SVProgressHUD

class AddCardVC: STPAddCardViewController, Alertable {

var stripeTool = StripeTools()

var paymentField = STPPaymentCardTextField()

var baseURLString: String? = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"
var baseURL: URL {
    if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        return url
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}

let theme = STPTheme()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    theme.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Regular ", size: 17)
    theme.emphasisFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Bold", size: 17)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white

    self.navigationItem.title = "ADD CARD"
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(dismiss as () -> Void))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(done as () -> Void))

}

func createCard(stripeId: String, card: STPCardParams, completion: @escaping (_ success: String, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    stripeTool.generateToken(card: card) { (token) in
        if(token != nil) {
            let customerId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "stripeId") as? String
            print(customerId!)

            let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("\(customerId!)/sources")

            var params = [String:String]()
            params["source"] = token!.tokenId

            let headers = ["Authorization": self.stripeTool.getBasicAuth()]
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers)
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON { response in
                   //    print(response)
//                        if let json = response.result.value as? JSONDictionary,
 //                            let carddata = json["data"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
//                            print(carddata)
//                        }
            }
        }
    }
}


@objc func dismiss() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func done() {
    let cardParams: STPCardParams = STPCardParams()
    cardParams.number = paymentField.cardNumber
    cardParams.expMonth = paymentField.expirationMonth
    cardParams.expYear = paymentField.expirationYear
    cardParams.cvc = paymentField.cvc

    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams, completion: {(result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let customerId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "stripeId") as? String
            self.createCard(stripeId: customerId!, card: cardParams, completion: { (success, error)  in
                if let error = error {
                    // Present error to user...
                }
                else {
                    print("card updated")
                }
            })

        }
        else {
            //handle error
        }

    })
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

StripeTools.swift

```
import Foundation
import Stripe

struct StripeTools {

private var stripeSecret = "key removed for Stack post"

func generateToken(card: STPCardParams, completion: @escaping (_ token: STPToken?) -> Void) {
    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: card) { token, error in
        if let token = token {
            completion(token)
        }
        else {
            print(error!)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}

func getBasicAuth() -> String{
    return "Bearer \(self.stripeSecret)"
}

}
```

I am looking to be able to have the credit card submitted to Stripe API when the customer taps done

Comment: `return "Bearer \(self.stripeSecret)"` <-- this means your Stripe secret API key is embedded in your app, and anyone who installs it could extract that key and use to create charges/refunds/transfers from your account. You should be submitting the generated token to a backend server and adding it to the customer there instead.

Comment: I think the way I would do this is create an instnace of [`STPCustomerContext`](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPCustomerContext.html) using an [ephemeral key](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api), and use that to update and manage the customer object on Stripe.